# Vlookup through named range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook where there are one main sheet and the rest sheets. Basically what my code does is it loops through sheets in a workbook not named "Main" and pulls values and puts them into appropriate column in Main sheet. IsError checks if Sheetname already exists in the list, if it does - it doesn't add values.
The layout of sheets is pretty messed up, with many merged cells - https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rnjr.jpg.

So in each sheet (except Main) I have block that contains values for "payroll", "consolidated social tax" and "miscellaneous expenditures". I came up with the idea of giving these blocks in each sheet name "Assumptions" and I made scope for each sheet so that "Assumptions" could be repeated in all sheets and I could loop through it. Here is the image of this block - https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A01h.jpg.

Code runs but I get #VALUE! errors on my Main sheet - https://imgur.com/a/H2TOFmW
I'm sorry for links, dont have permission to post images yet

Here is the code itself:

```
Sub Sheets()
Dim wsheet As Worksheet

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main")

  For Each wsheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

    If wsheet.Name <> "Main" Then
       Set nextEntry = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
       Set nextEntry_payroll = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AI").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
       Set nextEntry_consolidated_social_tax = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AJ").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
       Set nextEntry_miscellaneous_expenditures = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AK").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

       If IsError(Application.Match(wsheet.Name, .Range("G:G"), 0)) Then
          nextEntry.Value = wsheet.Name
          nextEntry_payroll.Value = wsheet.Application.VLookup("payroll", "Assumptions", 3, 0)
          nextEntry_consolidated_social_tax.Value = wsheet.Application.VLookup("consolidated social tax", "Assumptions", 3, 0)
          nextEntry_miscellaneous_expenditures.Value = wsheet.Application.VLookup("miscellaneous expenditures", "Assumptions", 3, 0)
       End If
    End If
  Debug.Print wsheet.Name
  Next wsheet
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know which line the error is on?

Comment: It doesn't give me an error, it runs. It's just the values it gives me in the main sheet as "#VALUE!"

Comment: Step through your code and find out which line errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the VLookup function from

```
wsheet.Application.VLookup("payroll", "Assumptions", 3, 0)
```

to

```
 Application.VLookup("payroll", wSheet.Range("Assumptions"), 3, 0)
```

and likewise for the other two.

Alternatively, you can change it use the VLookup worksheet function instead of calculating the value in VBA:

```
nextEntry_payroll.Formula = "=VLookup(""payroll"", " & wsheet.Name & "!Assumptions, 3, 0)"
```

and likewise for the other two. Try it to see the difference.

Comment: It works! Thank you! Could you please tell me why it was not working in my case?

Comment: It's because VLookup function differs when written as a worksheet formula and when called from VBA as Application.VLookup. To use VLookup as a worksheet worksheet function you can enter =VLOOKUP("payroll", Sheet2!Assumptions, 3, 0).